# What is the 8.8 mm R Criterion Curved Design?

Tags: design, product-design

Can you exlplain me what is the 8.8 mm R Criterion Curved Design? Apparently it is a criteria used by the UMi Touch phone. Why it uses 8.8 mm curves (what does this even mean? Do they mean that the radius of the fillets is 8.8 mm?) and what is the relation with the golden ratio? What is a cutting rate of 0.333% and why using 45 degrees ensures that?

- https://techlector.com/umi-touch-is-designed-to-be-one-with-the-nature/
- http://www.gizchina.com/2016/01/22/umi-touch-more-details-shipping-20th-march/

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you would draw curves according to the golden ratio you get something like the image above. They used these "golden standards" as a reference for the border-radius of the phones' screen. It's believed that this standard is appealing to the eye, that a human has a sort of natural, positive response to the golden ratio (because it's widely represented in nature). Products that are designed according to the golden ratio, would for that reason be more appealing to humans.

I'm not that familiar with the golden ratio, but I think the 8,8 mm means that if you would fit the curve inside a square, the square would be 8.8mm by 8.8mm.

"8.8 mm R Criterion Curved Design" just sounds fancy, I think.